# How to create a PDF containing text?

Tags: c#, itext

I want to create a PDF document containing some text that I have in the form of a string. This is what I have so far:

```
iTextSharp.text.Document d = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
string dosya = (@"C:\Deneme.pdf");
PdfWriter.GetInstance(d, new System.IO.FileStream(dosya, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
d.AddSubject(text);
```

Comment: why is all your code commented?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help. Use the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to improve the question.

Comment: Here is a [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bitext%5D+write+to+pdf+is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3Ayes) for you to find similar questions that might have the solution to whatever issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear because you don't mention if you want to create a PDF from scratch (which may be what you want to do based on your code sample) or if you want to add text to an existing PDF (which is what the subject of your question suggests).

In both cases, you should take a look at the official documentation.

If you want to create a PDF from scratch, take a look at the Hello World example:

```
public void CreatePdf(Stream stream) {
    // step 1
    using (Document document = new Document()) {
        // step 2
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        // step 3
        document.Open();
        // step 4
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!")); 
    }          
}
```

The value of `stream` can be any output stream (one that writes to memory, one that writes to a file,...).

If you want to add a `string` to an existing PDF, take a look at a `PdfStamper` example.

```
public static byte[] Stamp(byte[] resource) {
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
      PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
      ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
        canvas,
        Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 
        new Phrase("Hello people!"), 
        36, 540, 0
      );
    }
    return ms.ToArray();
  }
}
```

These examples were taken from a book I once wrote. You will find the examples through this link: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition

This answer assumes that you are using iText 5 (an assumption that is based on your code snippet). The most recent version is iText 7. That requires code that is totally different.